How can i store the oversampled data using smote in a separate variable?
After applying the Smote oversampling technique, I want to store only the newly generated values to X2 and y2. The independent features for X2 and the target variables for y2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
dataset = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/static/public/17/data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(y)
smt = SMOTE()
X1, y1 = smt.fit_resample(X, y)
#oversampled data using smote in the separate variables
#X2 = ?
#y2 = ?



Welcome to SO. I am afraid your question is quite unclear - what are these "separate variables" X2 and y2?

After applying the Smote oversampling technique, I want to store only the newly generated values to X2 and y2. The independent features for X2 and the target variables for y2.
